# Force SQL Server to parse "DDMMYYYY"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, date-format

I'm developing ETL from a file where dates are expressed in the format "DDMMYYYY", example "31012016".

I'd like to grab this string and pass it directly to the SQL text where data will be inserted. I don't want to parse it into C# DateTime to then format it to "YYYY-MM-DD" so that SQL Server parses it once more.

As I do currently, the date string is parsed once by .Net, then formated by .Net and printed in the SQL code, then parsed again by SQL Server. I want to grab the string from the flat file and place it directly into SQL code without any conversion.

SQL Server recognizes "YYYYMMDD", but it fails for "DDMMYYYY" with message:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Example:

```
DECLARE @datevar date = PARSE('31012016' as date using 'pt-BR');  
SELECT @datevar;
```

Is there any way to make it work?

I tried `PARSE('31012016' as date using 'pt-BR')` but raised exception. `TRY_PARSE` returns null. Also tried [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) but there doesn't seem to exist this style.

Comment: See http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/88152/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a date is represented as 8 numerals without any delimiters, SQL Server will always try to interpret it as `YYYYMMDD`. That format has deliberately been chosen as locale- or culture-independent (being also one of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard date formats, as a matter of fact), and there is no way to have the server interpret it as `DDMMYYYY` or in any other way.

So, either rearrange the date parts of your `DDMMYYYY` string to make it `YYYYMMDD`:

```
CONVERT(
  date,
  SUBSTRING(@datestring, 5, 4) + SUBSTRING(@datestring, 3, 2) + SUBSTRING(@datestring, 1, 2)
)
```

or insert delimiters to make it match one of the known delimited DMY formats, for instance `DD/MM/YYYY`:

```
CONVERT(
  date,
  STUFF(STUFF(@datestring, 5, 0, '/'), 3, 0, '/'),
  103  -- DD/MM/YYYY
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree that there is no direct conversion, but this is pretty simple, however performance will be bad, so stick with a bit of string manipulation!

```
    DECLARE @datevar DATE
    SET @datevar = TRY_PARSE(FORMAT(TRY_CAST('31012016' AS INT),'00/00/0000')
                   AS DATE USING 'PT-BR')
    SELECT @datevar;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, I could not find any way to get it to implicitly convert. This is the simplest I could come up with.

```
DECLARE @etldate varchar(max) = '31012016';

DECLARE @datevar date = CAST(SUBSTRING(@etldate, 3, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@etldate, 1, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@etldate, 5, 4) AS date);  
SELECT @datevar;
```